# Distribution with finite support.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

> If $f \in\mathcal D′(\Bbb R^n)$, is a distribution and support of this
>   distribution is a set of finite points in $\Bbb R^n$. Can anyone tell
>   me that what will be the general form of this distribution?

I will appreciate if you can give any insight or idea about it.

Answer (score 4):

http://www-math.mit.edu/~katrin/teach/18.155/delta.pdf

They are finite linear combinations of delta functions and their derivatives.

Comment: Thank you brian for this link. I will check it.
But how will we write any arbitrary distribution with finite support in the form of linear combinations of delta functions. Please elaborate it.

Comment: I read your pdf file, that is about the distribution which has only one point as support. But if the points in support are more than one then what will be the general form and how we will find it?

Comment: The general form will look like $\Sigma a_i D_{\alpha_i}\delta_{x_i}$, where the middle term is a differential operator, and the $x_i$ are points in the space.

Comment: Okay, Brian 
Can we prove that $\sum a_i. D_{\alpha_i}\delta_{x_i} $ is a general form by using induction method. As we know result is true for one point support? Thanks again.

Comment: @BrianRushton That link appears to be dead.  Do you have an updated link?

Comment: The link is not valid now, can you fix it?